# Typescript variable assignment causes linting error

Tags: typescript

I have a question about the following use of a typescript array. It all works fine but when I run it through the linter I get the following error, my assignment is obviously wrong.

> Array type using 'Array' is forbidden for simple types. Use 'T[]'
>   instead.

```
 export let data = [
  {
    "property": "value"
  }
 ];

export interface myInterface {
    property: string;
};

protected _collection: Array<myInterface>;
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: the edit you rejected made the <> characters you included in your question visible - they need to be escaped or they are not visible when the markup is rendered to HTML. This is also what [Murat K. mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693395/typescript-variable-assignment-causes-linting-error#41693578).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The linter probably just wants you to do:

```
protected _collection: myInterface[];
```

The types `myInterface[]` and `Array<myInterface>` are equivalent, but the linter seems to prefer the first.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the error stacktrace is not complete. The complete sentence is

> `Array type using 'Array<T>' is forbidden. Use 'T[]' instead.`

You have to code format it on SO. And the reason for the linter is here in the source code of palantir

https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/arrayTypeRule.ts#L81-L82

They want you to avoid using `Array<T>` in general. Instead you have to use it like this

```
protected _collection: myInterface[];
```

This is more like a preference from them.

Comment: the sentence I posted is the one it's generating for me.

Comment: I can see in your post that you copy pasted it with `Array<T>` but the displayed is `Array` that's what I meant. Nonetheless it's irrelevant for the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Use [] instead of the Array type.

```
protected _collection: myInterface[];
```

If you want to use the Array type there should a tslint rule to disable.